# Multithread issue "QBasicTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread"

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, pyqt5

I'm developing a program in Python 3.4, I'm using OpenCV to detect a symbol with a live video and I'm also using PyQt5 to develop the GUI. This is my code:

```
# coding=utf-8
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.2")

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
import threading

qtCreatorFile = "mainwindow.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow, threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        print("Index0")
        case=0
        self.iniciar_button.clicked.connect(self.teste,case)

    def teste(self, case):

        if case==0:
            self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
            t= threading.Thread(target=self.processo)
            t.start()
            print("case0")
        if case==1:
            print("case1")
            self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
            i=0
            while i==0:
                if self.iniciar2.clicked():
                    self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
                    d= threading.Thread(target=self.processo)
                    d.start()
                    i=1

##    @asyncio.coroutine    
    def processo(self):
        global garrafasA
        global garrafasR
        f=1
        while f==0:
            GPIO.setwarnings(False)
            GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
            entradaIR = 11
            GPIO.setup(entradaIR,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
            entrada = GPIO.input(entradaIR)
            if entrada==1:
                f=1

         (do something more here but nothing important)

        while flag1 == 1 and saida == 1 and x == 1: # Activar tapete de ACEITAÇÃO
            print ("Aceitacao")
            garrafasA += 1
            time.sleep(1.5)
            saida = GPIO.input(saidaIR)
            pwm1.start(DC)
            GPIO.output(motor1A,GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(motor1B,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(motor1E,GPIO.HIGH)
            saida = GPIO.input(saidaIR)
            self.nGarrafasA.display(garrafasA)
            if saida == 0:
                break

        entrada = GPIO.input(entradaIR)
        while flag2 == 1 and entrada == 0: # Inverter tapete de ACEITAÇÃO
            print ("inverter")
            if flag3 == 0:
                garrafasR += 1
                flag3 = 1
            time.sleep(1.5)
            pwm1.start(DC)
            GPIO.output(motor1A,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(motor1B,GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(motor1E,GPIO.HIGH)
            entrada = GPIO.input(entradaIR)
            self.nGarrafasR.display(garrafasR)

        entrada = GPIO.input(entradaIR)
        while flag2 == 1 and entrada == 1: # Parar tapete de entrada na devolução              
            print ("Entrada",entrada)
            print ("Parar tapete")
            GPIO.output(motor1E,GPIO.LOW)
            pwm1.stop()
            flag2=0
            case=1
            self.teste(case)
            return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    garrafasA = 0
    garrafasR = 0
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I created a new thread to be able to have the GUI running and have at the same time the symbol detection on the function "processo", but once this function ends it returns to the "case1" on function "teste" to wait for the button "iniciar2.
Here is the problem after he print the "case1" and change the page to index 2 I get the message "QBasicTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread".

Anyone have idea of what I'm doing wrong? Someone could help me? I'm dealing with this error a while  ago and I can't figure what is the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide the code for at least the `processo` method. A [mcve] is typically expected when asking for debugging help.

Comment: I already updated the original post hope someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

**QBasicTimer.stop** Failed. Possibly trying to stop from a different thread
**QBasicTimer.start** Timers cannot be started from another thread

```
# I don't know why that message is occured....
# There is List Control to print Log Message In Main UI class

# ===================================
# Thread Class
# ===================================
class CThreadEvents(QThread):
    def __init__(self, pParent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.m_parent = pParent

    def run(self):
        strTemp = ""
        v = 0

        while self.running:
            v = v + 1
            self.m_parent.setLogMessage(str(v))
            time.sleep(0.01)
```

```py
# ===================================
# Main UI Class
# ===================================
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def pushButton_LaunchEvent(self):
        self.t1 = CThreadEvents(self)
        self.t1.start()

    def setLogMessage(tempMessage):
        self.listWidgetLog.addItem(QListWidgetItem(tempMessage))
```